# How to check if a rent is already taken between 2 dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to compare two dates on for the start of the rent and the end of the rent but with a database where some vehicles could have already rented at thoses dates

i've already have a code that block the user to book a car between two dates but after that it's still blocked

```
if( empty($content) ){
        extract($_POST); // here i extract my _post
        if( !empty($idmembre) ){

            $vehicule = execReq( "SELECT * FROM vehicule WHERE idvehicule=:idvehicule", array(
                'idvehicule' => $idvehicule
            ));
            $infoVehicule = $vehicule->fetch();
            $agence = $infoVehicule['agences_idagences'];
            $timestamp1 = strtotime($date_heure_depart);
            $timestamp2 = strtotime($date_heure_fin); // here i create two timestamps to compare with what i have en my database
            $date_deja_prise = execReq( "SELECT * FROM commande WHERE vehicule_idvehicule=:idvehicule", array(
                'idvehicule' => $idvehicule
            ));
            while( $date = $date_deja_prise->fetch() ){
                if( !empty($date) ){ // here if one vehicle has a date of rent it checks evry one to check if the date is taken
                    $date_debut = strtotime($date['date_heure_depart']);
                    $date_fin = strtotime($date['date_heure_fin']);
                    if( ($date_debut <= $timestamp1 || $timestamp2 <= $date_fin) ){
                        $content .= '<div class="alert alert-danger">Le véhicule '.$infoVehicule['titre'].' est déjà louer du '.$date['date_heure_depart'].' au '.$date['date_heure_fin'].' inclu</div>';
                    }
                }
            }
            if( empty($content) ){
                $nb_de_jour_timestamp = $timestamp2 - $timestamp1;
                $nb_de_jour = $nb_de_jour_timestamp/86400;
                $prix_journalier = $nb_de_jour * $infoVehicule['prix_journalier'];
                execReq( "INSERT INTO commande VALUES(NULL, $idmembre, $idvehicule, $agence, :date_heure_depart, :date_heure_fin, $prix_journalier, now())", array(
                    'date_heure_depart' => date("Y-m-d", $timestamp1),
                    'date_heure_fin' => date("Y-m-d", $timestamp2)
                ));
                $content = '<div class="alert alert-success">Votre reservation a été effectué !</div>';
            }
        } else {
            $content .= '<div class="alert alert-danger">Pour passer une commande vous devez créer un compte <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#inscription">cliquez ici</a> pour vous en créer un</div>';
        }
    }
```

so basicaly it can create a line in my phpmyadmin page where the car is booked for some period of time and after that if i try to book an other car but all the dates are differents i can't

Comment: In your INSERT query, why are you mixing both placeholders and variable interpolation? Stick to placeholders for _all_ values instead and there's less risk of nasty security issues going forward.

Comment: `if( !empty($date) )` seems like an unnecessary check. I don't see how that variable ever could be empty since it's set in `while($date = $date_deja_prise->fetch())`. You can't get an empty record back from the database. If you get no records back, the loop won't even be entered.

Comment: The logic for range ovelap is: `($existing_start <= $new_end && $existing_end >= $new_start)`

Comment: If it was me, I'd forget about all the php stuff for now, and instead see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is this line `if( ($date_debut <= $timestamp1 || $timestamp2 <= $date_fin) ){`. You are only checking if thenew start time is <= than an existing start time and if the new end time is >= than an existing one. You need to check if either the start or end date is between an existing date.

`if( ($date_debut <= $timestamp2 && $timestamp1 <= $date_fin) ){`

Comment: There are two more cases for an overlap - when one range is within the other.

Comment: Thank you so much i wasn't paying much attention to that and now it works perfectly :D thank @magnus-eriksson for the not so usefull check of the empty date